# Mingw bug?: std::filesystem::copy fails with filesystem error when file exist, even when the copy_option to overwrite_existing is defined

Tags: c++, c++17, mingw, std-filesystem

MINGW v. 8.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: P:/MSYS2/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: P:/MSYS2/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - works

trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

constexpr auto * f1 ="C:\\TEMP\\fred_test.txt";
constexpr auto * f2 ="C:\\TEMP\\fred_test.txt~";

void create_file(char const* p){
    std::ofstream ofs1{p};
}

int main() {
    try{
        fs::remove(f1);
        fs::remove(f2);
        create_file(f1);
        create_file(f2);
        fs::copy_file(f1, f2, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
    } catch (fs::filesystem_error const& fe) {
        std::cout << fe.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
filesystem error: cannot copy file: File exists [C:\TEMP\fred_test.txt] [C:\TEMP\fred_test.txt~]
```

With msvc:

```
success
```

Running CMake with: P:\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:[***]\test_fs

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test_fs)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(test_fs main.cpp)
```

Can someone reproduce this also?

Comment: Seems like it might be similar to/the same as https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/699/. That was filed under MinGW 7 (which didn't officially support filesystem, so the issue was closed) but I'm guessing the same bug exists in 8 (which does)

Comment: Just filed it as bugreport. We will see what happens: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/852/